# getStartOffset returns wrong value of file in assets folder after upgrade of assembly conditions

Tags: java, android, assets, android-api-levels

The method `getStartOffset()` does not work correctly after I upgraded assembly conditions.

Following fragment of code worked fine to build app with **api 19** (*Android Plugin **1.5.0** + Gradle version **2.2.1***), but when I try do same with **api 25** and other building conditions (*Android Plugin **2.2.0** + Gradle version **2.14.1***), `getStartOffset()` returns value bigger length of file. Returned length is true.
In fact, the reading "png"-file isn't a image, I gave it extension PNG according to the requirements of aapt.

```java
AssetFileDescriptor in = null;
FileInputStream fin = null;
FileChannel channel = null;
try {
      in = context.getAssets().openFd(file); // .png
      fin = in.createInputStream();
      channel = fin.getChannel();
      int length = (int) in.getLength(); // channel.size();
      int offSet = (int) in.getStartOffset();
      MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,
        0, length + offSet);
      ...
      ...
     }
```

What is the problem? Thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **normal** behavior. I had to look at the contents of `APK file` to hash editor. To my surprise, my PNG file appeared twice included in the `APK-file`: its first entry offset from the start was 52 bytes, in the second case, the startOffset was more than 2MB. I.e. *StartOffset* is the shift in the *apk-package*.

Excitement was in vain. Everything is working:

```
MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, offSet,   length);
int spos = 0;
while(spos < length) {
 ......
}
```